# What does flow {| brace pipe |} syntax do?

Tags: syntax, flowtype

What does [this](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/bc33f2e5382f454f8576e23e9a604c929d21e013/src/utilities/extendSchema.js#L36) Flow syntax mean/do?

```
type Options = {|
  assumeValid?: boolean,
  commentDescriptions?: boolean,
|};
```

I can't seem to find where the `{|` ... `|}` syntax is documented.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is Flowtype's [Exact Object type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types) syntax.