# What does {| ... |} mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Reading through a javascript codebase, I encounter a block of code that looks like

```
export type RouteReducerProps = {|
  error?: Error,
  isResolving: boolean,
  isResolved: boolean,
  hasFailed: boolean,
|};
```

This looks like a javascript object literal definition, but I've never seen a javascript object literal with vertical bars inside the curly braces. What do those do?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393027/what-does-flow-brace-pipe-syntax-do

Comment: So it is. I didn't find either of those when searching for `{|`, or `{| ... |}`. Then again, I didn't find my question either. :/ I think there is a larger problem here of how to search for syntax on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 14):

This syntax is specific to [Flow](https://flow.org/), a static type checker for javascript. It defines an [Exact Object Type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types), which is an object for which a only a few specified keys are valid. In the example above, only the keys `'error?'`, `'isResolving'`, `'isResolved'`, and `'hasFailed'` can be defined on the object `RouteReducerProps`.